# Jquery - Access variables specific to each row?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a web page and using php Im quering a database and displaying the results in a table like so:

```
<table id="tablelist">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Header1</th>
<th>Header2</th>
<th>Header3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Info here1</td>
<td>Info here1</td>
<td class="actions">Action1 - Action2 - Action3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Info here2</td>
<td>Info here2</td>
<td class="actions">Action1 - Action2 - Action3</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Now each row has unique information specific to that row that is from the database. For example the primary id, a date and category. When someone clicks an action for any of the rows I need to obtain those 2 pieces of information specific to the row they clicked. Currently I tried doing this:

```
<div class="row_data">{info2 in json format}</div>    
<tr>
    <td>Info here1</td>
    <td>Info here1</td>
    <td class="actions">Action1 - Action2 - Action3</td>
    </tr>
<div class="row_data">{info2 in json format}</div>    
<tr>
    <td>Info here2</td>
    <td>Info here2</td>
    <td class="actions">Action1 - Action2 - Action3</td>
    </tr>
```

So when someone clicked on an action link it would get the previous value of row_data, which is in json format. I would use jquery to parse the json value and use the information found within the rest of the jquery code. But I was told this is invalid html and not recommended. What would be a recommended/optimal way of storying dynamic data per row to use when an action is clicked so I can reference it in my jquery code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is use HTML 5's data attributes:

```
<tr id="foo" data-something="put whatever you want in here">
    <!-- content -->
</tr>
```

You can then access the information you stored there with

```
$("#foo").data("something")
```

The value of `data-something` can be anything you like (as long as it's filtered through `htmlspecialchars` if you are echoing it straight from PHP), and you can use multiple data attributes if that's more convenient (usually it is).

There's also a [post by John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) on the subject.

Comment: but if I had id="foo" for each row isnt that a no no? Having duplicate ids on the page?

Comment: @John: Of course. That was only an example. You can also do `$(this).closest("tr").data(...)` or choose to put the attributes on some other element entirely.

Comment: The suggestion is to use data-{name} attributes not to use foo for all ids

Comment: @Jon thanks for the explanation. I only asked because I was reading up best practices for jquery and it says its faster to select from an id than a class selector but in this case you would have duplicate ids.

Comment: @John: What you should take home from that best practice is "don't use classes when an id would be more appropriate". Which has no relation to the subject at hand. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Jon's suggestion works, but I hate embedding data in HTML, so I would create a JSON map from id to the data, and add those ids to the TRs. From the click handler, you grab the TR's id and find the data from the map.

Comment: Conceptually this is embedding data (the ids) in HTML just the same though. Admittedly, it does have the advantage of allowing you to have valid non-HTML 5 markup without adding extra elements just for the data.

Comment: @Jon: You are fully correct, plus this solution is more flexible - for example when using partials (partial views on server side script), it is easier to implement `data-` attributes than embedding the whole script in a "non-messy" way.

Answer (score 0):

I think i'm tired and may have misunderstood this so please forgive if I suggest something totally wrong...

So say some one clicks action 1 in any row. Perhaps you would begin with a click listener on each link assuming you give your links a class called "action" ...

```
<tr>
    <td class="json_info" style="display:none">{your json string}</td>
    <td>Info 1</td>
    <td>Info 2</td>
    <td><a class="action">action link</a></td>
</tr>

$('.action').click(function(){
    var json = $(this).parent().find('.json_info').html();
});
```

If the html for json_info is a properly formatted json string then it should be able to be read as json right out of this jquery selection call.